# If there is a function that is only called by the __init__ in my class, can it work as a class function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a function that is only called by the **init** in my class,

I want to know whether it can be a class function?

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't matter where it is called. If it doesn't use `self`, then you can. If it does, then no.

(If it uses neither `self` nor `cls` (the type object), it would be better to make it a static method, not a class method.)